# After joining with AD user, changing [User@domain@host] to [user@host]

Tags: centos, prompt, active-directory, domain

My CentOS machine joined a domain with an AD so that I can log in with ssh with the credentials from the AD. Everything works fine, but now the username looks quite ugly with `user@domain@host` in it.

I want to change it, that it only shows the user I logged in with and the host name. Since the name is already `\u@\h`, I saw no option to fix this on this way. In the `sshd.conf` file is nothing (not that there should be anything), also in the `sssd.conf` and the others. Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit:
Found a solution for this (with the help of Jeff Schaller):
I just had to edit `/etc/bashrc` and replace `PS1="[\u@\h \W]\\$ "` with `PS1="[${USER%@*}@\h \W]\$ "`. The problem was, that I connected with SSH every time, or so that's what I found out.

Comment: I have no experience with AD on linux, but I suspect that `@domain` is truly a part of the username, at least on your CentOS machine. That would allow it to integrate with AD without overriding any (e.g. custom) local accounts. Otherwise, someone with an AD username of `root` would have superuser privileges on your box, even though `root` has no special meaning to AD.

Comment: Is there a remaining environment variable that's set to only (user) as opposed to (user@host)? Then you could use that instead of \u in PS1.

Comment: show us `echo $PS1`

Comment: it shows '[\u@\h \W]\$' @AFSHIN

Comment: @JeffSchaller Sadly I didnt found anything I can replace \u with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `\u` prompt-expansion, you could ask PS1 to expand `$USER` by stripping off any ampersand and trailing text; change your local or global PS1 definition

from:

```
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
```

to:

```
PS1='[${USER%@*}@\h \W]\$ '
```

This allows for more shenanigans than the (fixed) `\u` expansion if USER is not readonly, but might be acceptable.

```
[bob@host ~]$ USER=notreallyroot
[notreallyroot@host ~]$ USER=notreallyroot@domain.here
[notreallyroot@host ~]$
```

Comment: Thanks for the Input with $USER and the other PS1 definition, but the "problem" is still there, even when I changed the $USER manually (what we dont want to, because everyone who logs in from the domain should only see their AD Username). `[SD@domain.de@host ~]$` When I look $USER up, it shows the right username. Could it be, that it doesnt work because its the name from the AD?

Comment: I lost you when you said $USER shows the right username. What's the value of $USER after you log in (before you mess with it) -- "user@domain", or "user"? Either one should be properly expanded by `${USER%@*}` to be just the "user" part. If USER isn't being set, what is? `set | grep SD@domain.de` may give a breadcrumb to follow.

Comment: If I look up user with `echo $USER` the output is `SD@domain.de` before I changed anything. I tried around with the `${USER%@*}` part in PS1, nothing changed. I even removed the whole User-part to see if my PS1 was broken or something, but everything works like it should (except the main problem). But I will run `set | grep SD@domain.de` at monday and report if something interesting happens, thanks for your help so far.

Comment: if you just do `echo "${USER%@*}"` at a shell prompt, does it do the right thing and display just `SD`? Sounds like your shell isn't performing the parameter expansion correctly. Double-check that you used single-quotes around the PS1 definition.